# Why am I getting a "program is finished running (dropped off bottom) error?

Tags: mips

I'm not sure why this is giving me a dropped off error here. Anyone know how to fix this?
I'm trying to create a program that can convert between decimal, hexadecimal, and binary in MIPS. I'm supposed to request the input data type and the input data, and then request the output data type, and output the data. Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
#Provide data variable and data as an input and output
.Data
Input1: .asciiz "Kindly enter the input X:"
Input2: .asciiz "Please provide the number system Y details:"
Output: .asciiz "\nThe result will be R:"

#starts global main
.Globl main
main:
addi $A0, $zero, 2
addi $A1, $zero, 15

#get the input value dropped by the user
getX:

li $M0, 4
la $N0, Input1
syscall
li $M0, 5
syscall
blt $M0, $zero, getX

move $K0, $M0

#get the value of the number system dropped by the user
getY:

li $M0, 4
la $N0, Input2
syscall
li $M0, 5
syscall
blt $M0, $A0, getY
bgt $M0, $A1, getY

add $K1, $zero, $M0

li $M0, 4
la $N0, Output
syscall

add $N0, $zero, $K0
add $N1, $zero, $K1

jal convert

li $M0, 15
syscall

#perform conversion over the respective input and number system
convert:
addi $sp, $sp, -16

sw $A3, 12($sp)

#Applying counter that is used to check that how many
#times values will be popped up from the stack
sw $A0, 8($sp)
sw $A1, 4($sp)
sw $ra, 0($sp)

add $A0, $zero, $N0
add $A1, $zero, $N1

beqz $A0, end

div $K4, $A0, $A1
rem $K3, $A0, $A1
add $sp, $sp, -4
sw $K3, 0($sp)

add $N0, $zero, $K4
add $N1, $zero, $A1
addi $A3, $A3, 1

jal convert

end:

lw $ra, 0($sp)
lw $A1, 4($sp)
lw $A0, 8($sp)
lw $A3, 12($sp)
beqz $A3, done
lw $N0, 16($sp)
li $M0, 1
syscall

#operation performed
done:
addi $sp, $sp, 20
jr $ra

#return to the main
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

I don't see you calling this so at the end of your done branch it doesn't end the system. Opcode 10 will do this for you in MIPS.

Comment: i added these lines after the jr $ra line at the very end, and it didn't fix the error

Comment: They won't do anything there, since `jr $ra` already moved `$pc` before it could reach them.

Answer (score 0):

```
jal convert

li $M0, 15
syscall

#perform conversion over the respective input and number system

#your problem is here
convert:
addi $sp, $sp, -16
```

This is actually a pretty common mistake (we've all been guilty of it so no judgment here.) In assembly, a label simply existing *does not* prevent code from being executed. In order to have this code run the way you want, you need to insert the following.

```
jal convert

li $M0, 15
syscall

li $v0,10    #linux/mars/spim exit code
syscall      #this is how you properly exit main and return to the OS


#thanks to the above, execution will not fall through to here anymore
#perform conversion over the respective input and number system
convert:
addi $sp, $sp, -16
```